# How can the V and Q functions take the expectation over a sum where the number of summands is random?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, value-functions, probability-theory

Assume the existence of a Markov Decision Process consisting of:

- State space $S$
- Action space $A$
- Transition model $T: S \times A \times S \to [0,1]$
- Reward function $R: S \times A \times S \to \mathbb{R}$
- Distribution of initial state $p_0: S \to [0,1]$

and a policy $\pi: S \to A$.

The $V$ and $Q$-functions take expectations of the sum of future rewards.

Let's start off by $r_0:= R(x_0,\pi(x_0),x_1)$, where $\pi$ is the current policy while $x_0 \sim p_0$ and $x_1 \sim T(x_0,\pi(x_0),-)$ are random variables. With setting $\mu_i:= T(x_i,\pi(x_i),-),\rho_i:=R(x_i,\pi(x_i),-)$, I obtain

$$E[r_0]= \int_{\mathbb{R}} r d\mu_0^{\rho_0} = \int_S R(x_0,\pi(x_0),-)d\mu_0,$$

where $\mu_i^{\rho_i}:= \mu_i\circ \rho_i^{-1}$ is the pushforward of $\mu_i$ under random variable $\rho_i$. But the above quantity still depends on $x_0$ as both $\mu_o$ and $\rho_0$ depend on $x_0$. Intuitively, I would guess that one has to calculate the integral over every occuring random variable to obtain the overall expectation, i.e. $$E[r_0]= \int_S\int_S R(x_0,\pi(x_0),x_1)d\mu_0(x_1)dp_0(x_0)$$ is that correct ?

Now, the $V$ and $Q$-functions take the expectation over the sum $R_{\tau} = \sum^T_{t=\tau}\gamma^{t-\tau}r_t$, where the instant of termination $T$ itself is a random variable, and, besides that, the agent does not know its distribution, as it is not even included in the MDP model.

How can I take the expectation over a sum where the number of summands is random?

We cannot just calculate $\sum^{E[T]}(\dots)$, because $E[T]$ might not even be an integer.

Comment: Hi. Can you please simplify your question? Ask one question per post, if you want to attract the attention of more people. It seems to me you're asking multiple questions here.

Comment: For the question related to $V$ and $Q$ I feel like you are overthinking it (either that, or I don't understand your question). The sum of $R_\tau$ is a random variable so it is fine for it to have an expectation. You can circumvent the problem of $E[T]$ (the length of the trajectory) by just assuming, that the trajectory is infinite and that after $T$ the reward is zero.

Comment: @nbro Yes, I will split it into serveral questions.